# IDEA keeps adding node_modules dependences to linked Eclipse .classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, node.js, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with the option "Link created IntelliJ IDEA modules to Eclipse project files", as the Eclipse `.classpath` files are our de-facto standard for managing dependencies.

Some of our projects mix Java and NodeJS. After installing NodeJS plugins, IDEA keeps adding the following line to the `.classpath`:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/basket.angular.ui node_modules"/>
```

It is somewhat annoying. Currently, I avoided to commit these changes, as I do not know what the consequences are for other Eclipse users. (I only found out that kind="con" means container.)

Is it possible to avoid that these lines are added? Or should I just commit the changes, as they are safe?

Comment: I wouldn't think they're safe. Anyone without a User Library in their preferences named "basket.angular.ui node_modules" would get a red exclamation point on the project because of an unresolvable build path. And why is it even a User Library instead of a proper container?

Comment: @nitind I think you are right that commiting the change is a bad idea. User library vs container? The node_modules directory contains NodeJS' external javascript libraries, so "user library" seems to be OK (if I understand the difference between user libraries and containers in the context of .classpath files correctly).